# Passing parameters to an RSS Feed from a Data View Web Part in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, dataviewwebpart

I have a Data View Web Part in Sharepoint that is being fed from an RSS Feed. I have the Data Source configured properly to read the RSS Feed and I have added several runtime parameters. My question is, how do I supply these values at runtime? For example, one of the parameters is startDate and this should be populated with the current date.

Answer (score 0):

after some quick googling i found these date functions which may help
http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSL-Ref/Tutorials/Date-Time/dt1.html

and this article looks to describe how to get querystring variables into a dataview web part
http://itfootprint.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/using-query-string-and-data-view-webpart/

jt